# Exact sequence given effective divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Suppose $Y \subset X$ is a closed subscheme of $X$. If $I$ is the ideal sheaf associated to $Y$, we have a short exact sequence

$$
0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow \mathscr O_X \rightarrow \mathscr O_Y \rightarrow 0,
$$

where $I = \mathscr O_X(-D)$, and $D = Y$ is an effective divisor.

My question is, given any effective divisor $D$, is there always such a sequence? What about effective divisors that are not irreducible, not reduced, or neither of the two? What about effective $\mathbb Q$-divisors?

Suppose for instance $D = 2F$, where $F$ is prime. We do have a sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathscr O_X(F) \rightarrow \mathscr O_X(D) \rightarrow \mathscr O_F(D) \rightarrow 0.
$$
If we take
$$
0 \rightarrow \mathscr O_X \rightarrow \mathscr O_X(D) \rightarrow Q \rightarrow 0,
$$
what is $Q$, in other words what is $\mathscr O_X / \mathscr O_X(-D)$? Does it even make sense to speak of $D$ as a scheme, and therefore of $\mathscr O_D$?

Thank you!

Comment: To start with, $I \ne {\mathcal O}_X(D)$, one may have $I = {\mathcal O}_X(-D)$, but only if $Y = D$.

Comment: Yes, I corrected the typo.

Comment: Your $Q$ is ${\mathcal O}_D(D)$ (if $D$ is a Cartier divisor) and ${\mathcal O}_X/{\mathcal O}_X(-D) = {\mathcal O}_D$. If $D$ is a Cartier divisor, the meaning of ${\mathcal O}_D$ is obvious. If $D$ is a Weil divisor (on a normal scheme), the (reflexive) sheaf ${\mathcal O}_X(-D)$ is well defined as a sheaf of ideals on $X$ and provides a scheme structure on $D$.

Comment: Thank you. If I'm not mistaken that means yes, we do always have such a sequence.